# is there an easy way to make a windows service?

Tags: windows, windows-services

Question: Is there a way to make a program run with out logging in that doesn't involve the long painful task of creating a windows service, or is there an easy way to make a simple service?

---

Info: I'm working on a little project for college which is a simple distributed processing program. I'm going to harness the computers on campus that are currently sitting completely idle and make my own little super computer. but to do this I need the client running on my target machines.

Through a little mucking around on the internet I find that what I need is a service, I also find that this isn't something quite as simple as making a scheduled task or dropping a .bat file into the start up folder.

I don't need a lot. if I could just get it to call "python cClient.py" i'm completely set. Is there an easy way to do this? like adding a key in the registry some where? or do I have to go through the whole song and dance ritual that microsoft has made for setting up a service?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you already have the executable you wish to run as a service you can use "sc" built into the OS already. Microsoft details the procedure here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192

```
example: sc create "My Service" c:\temp\executable.exe
```

> C:\Users\somebody>sc create

```
DESCRIPTION:      Creates a service entry in the registry and Service Database. USAGE: sc <server> create [service name] [binPath= ] <option1> <option2>...

OPTIONS: NOTE: The option name includes the equal sign.
      A space is required between the equal sign and the value.   type= <own|share|interact|kernel|filesys|rec>
       (default = own)   start= <boot|system|auto|demand|disabled|delayed-auto>
       (default = demand)   error= <normal|severe|critical|ignore>
       (default = normal)   binPath= <BinaryPathName>   group= <LoadOrderGroup>   tag= <yes|no>   depend= <Dependencies(separated by / (forward slash))>   obj= <AccountName|ObjectName>        (default = LocalSystem)   DisplayName= <display name>   password= <password>
```

Comment: supplement your post with http://alexkr.com/posts/69/a-trick-to-create-a-service-using-scexe-under-windows-xp/ and you got exactly what I wanted. a simple as possible way of creating a services. thanks.

Comment: Sc doesn't create a service from any executalble. It helps to maintain and administer Windows services. I.e Create, Start, Stop, Query or Delete etc.

Comment: elaborate jocab. have found that i can't just make a service out of something such as note pad, but found this site: http://www.muukka.net/programming/service/ which gives me all i need to know about making a service in C. is there something you know of Jacob that can make a service out of any executable? or even better, something like a .bat?

Answer (score 2):

The Windows NT Resource Kit introduced the [Srvany.exe command-line utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890), which can be used to start any Windows NT/2000/2003 application as a service.

You can download Srvany.exe [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17657).

Comment: is this something I will have to download? or is this available by default in windows 7?

Comment: @Narcolapser: you have to download it.

Comment: that's a draw back in my particular situation because I need to install this service on 30-50 computers. each extra step in the installation process can make it a little drag. other wise I like you answer. clean and simple.

Answer (score 1):

Use Visual Studio and just create yourself a Windows Service project. I think you'll find it very easy.

Comment: I'm running Linux. I programmed my entire system in Gedit(basically linux's version of notepad) and command line. only my target machines are windows. <Opinion>Besides, anything to do with MS VS is an involved process. Especially when you are used to the slim and trim feeling of command line.</Opinion>

Comment: Your opinion is badly uninformed. Just creating the new project creates a skeleton Windows Service that works.

Comment: perhaps. but in the years i used VS before i moved to linux, it never quite felt that simple even though it felt like it should. :/

Comment: How many years was that? The .NET template for Windows Service has always been pretty easy to use.

Comment: 6 or so. it was the first IDE I used. Got to college and started using Dr. Java because it was required for class. Which was a joke of an IDE, but after using the beast that is visual studio, having my IDE boot up in 3 seconds compared to maybe a minute got my spoiled and since then I've gone command line and notepad. differences in taste really. I like it when things are kept simple and nimble. windows and Visual Studio have not show that to me. so I use linux and code with notepad/command line. xD

Answer (score 0):

Can you [schedule a task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task)? More info [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770904.aspx).

Comment: I would love to, but I'm not seeing how I might be able to do it with no loged in user. I need a task that will start when the computer starts up with out a log in. I just need it to start a simple task. if i can do that from a scheduled task fantastic, that is ideal, but if not, I have to write my own service.

Comment: There are a number of choices as to when you would like to run the task. One of them is when computer starts – this before a user is logged in.

Comment: ah, it has been so long since I've messed with scheduled tasks that I forgot that was even an option. but even so, it isn't working, greatly to my dismay. I'm not sure why, i set up a task to run that would connect my desktop to my netbook and stream a litte string using python. testing the script when i was logged in it worked just fine, so I rebooted. I watched my command line on my netbook waiting for my computer to talk to me, but nothing came. I looked at the login screen on my desktop and a blank command line on my netbook saddened. any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: bah, it may have worked this time. curse you windows and your inconsistency!

Comment: I've waited about 5 minutes now at the login screen. nothing. is there a way to make this more consistent?

Comment: i figure for now this will suffice as I get this project off the ground. so thanks for now, but I'll create a service in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a startup script and globally apply it to your machines via group policy - just add it via gpedit.msc:

[image: Add startup script via group policy]

Comment: eeeh. I really like this, but i'm not doing this with the backing of computing services, technically not even the ok of them. Computing services doesn't care what we do to the computers as long as it doesn't interfere with other people. Is there a way to do this locally per machine?

Comment: Well, since it's group policy, you could add the machines to a special Active Directory group to which you would attach the script. If you want to do it directly on each machine, just edit using gpedit.msc.

Comment: the former is not an option just because I don't have admin privileges on our domain, but the later is certainly a possibility.